# Apt-get update error after dpkg --add-architecture amd64 - Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: apt, server, dpkg, 64-bit, arm64

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and trying to add architecture amd64 but I am unable to update the packages after that.

Below are some relevant command outputs :

```
$ dpkg --print-architecture
arm64
```

```
$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
amd64
```

now when i try to execute `sudo apt-get update`, I get following error

```
Hit:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease                  
Ign:5 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:5 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 Packages
Ign:6 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err:5 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 18.208.205.157 80]
Ign:6 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:7 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err:9 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 18.208.205.157 80]
Ign:10 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:11 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Err:13 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 18.208.205.157 80]
Ign:14 http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Err:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
Ign:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Fetched 163 kB in 1s (141 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 18.208.205.157 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 18.208.205.157 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us-east-1.ec2.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 18.208.205.157 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.150 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any help on how can i fix this would be really great. Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason of adding `amd64` architecture to an ARM install? `amd64` software won't work anyway. You can't "fix" this because there is n `ubuntu-ports` repo for `amd64`. You are doing something wrong.

Comment: You are NOT "unable to update the packages". The existing repos do update.

Comment: Really it can be fixed by editing `sources.list`. But I want to know what is your goal first.

Comment: @Pilot6, many thanks for the reply. My goal is to install tableau server, however i later understood that tableau does not support ARM. But, just for my knowlegde can you please share how i can update the packages while using amd64 arch?

Comment: @Pilot6, in case you know of some good article reads, can you please share so i can more clearly understand ARM and AMD architectures

Comment: You already updated packages. You can ignore this error. Or add `[arm64]` in `sources.list`.

Comment: @Pilot6, may be my understanding is in correct in that case. can you please confirm. I see packages installed under architecture arm64, but when i tried to run a amd64 application, it gave me a error saying "Dependency is not satisfiable: fontconfig". so i thought that i need to install packages for architecture amd64, but when i execute apt-get update i got 404 for all the links.

Comment: It is unrelated. Adding `amd64` was useless anyway. It is incompatible with your CPU. you get 404, because there is no such repo for amd64.

Comment: can you please share any articles where i can understand the concepts in more depth. how do you know its incompatible? what are the major differences betwwen amd64 and arm64. Would really like to know more about. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have any articles. You can google them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually can undo it by doing this command on the terminal

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture amd64
```

This will remove the architecture restoring it back to the default architecture

This worked for me. Not to argue but this could have saved you some time.